# AS3 playing a second audio file after the first is complete

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, compiler-errors

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm loading a sound like this:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("audio/filename.mp3"));
mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();
```

Then I'm adding a listener and trying to call a function with the SOUND_COMPLETE event, like this:

```
mySoundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,audioComplete);
function audioComplete(Event:Event){
trace("done!");
}
```

However, I keep getting this error: "1046:Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:Event."

Can anyone give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @The_asMan importing the Event class is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those of you who responded.  I ended up finding a better way to do this.  If anyone runs into the same problem, here is what is working for me:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var mySoundURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myfile.mp3");
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound.load(mySoundURL);
mySoundChannel = mySound.play();
mySoundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, endMySound);

function endMySound(e:Event):void{
trace("sound is complete!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
function audioComplete(Event:Event){
```

to

```
function audioComplete(event:Event){
```

AS is case sensitive. `event` is not the same as `Event`. `Event` is the name of a class. `event` is the name you are assigning to the local variable of the type `Event`

Moreover, sound is loaded in Flash asynchronously. This means that when you call `sound.load()`, Flash Player will start loading the sound on a new thread and continue the next lines of code while the sound is loading. The `Event.COMPLETE` event is triggered when this sound is fully loaded, **NOT** when the sound has finished playing.

to trigger a function when a sound has finished playing, use `setTimeout`

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("audio/filename.mp3"));
mySound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);

function soundLoaded(e:Event):void {
    mySound.play();
    setTimeout(audioComplete, mySound.length);
}
function audioComplete(){
    trace("done!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for clearing this up for me.  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`function audioComplete(Event:Event){`

to

`function audioComplete(e:Event){`

It's a good idea to not use class names for your variable names. It can confuse the compiler and programmers trying to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Import the Event class:
`import flash.events.Event`

```
package
{
    
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    
    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        
        private var _sound : Sound:
        private var _soundChannel : SoundChannel:

        public function Test() : void
        {
            playSound("audio/filename.mp3");
        }
    
        private function playSound(url : String) : void
        {
            // start sound here
            _sound = new Sound();
            _sound.load(new URLRequest(url));
            _soundChannel = mySound.play();

            _soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete);
        }

        private function onSoundComplete(event : Event) : void
        {
            // sound is complete
            _soundChannel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete);

            // play next sound
        }
    }   
}
```